# Invoking binary in aws lambda with rust

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, aws-lambda, rust-cargo

So I have the following rust aws lambda function:

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use lambda_http::{run, service_fn, Body, Error, Request, RequestExt, Response};
use lambda_http::aws_lambda_events::serde_json::json;

/// This is the main body for the function.
/// Write your code inside it.
/// There are some code example in the following URLs:
/// - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-rust-runtime/tree/main/examples
async fn function_handler(_event: Request) -> Result<Response<Body>, Error> {
    // Extract some useful information from the request
    let program = Command::new("./myProggram")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process");

    let data = String::from_utf8(program.stdout).unwrap();
    let parsed = data.split("\n").filter(|x| !x.is_empty()).collect::<Vec<&str>>();

    // Return something that implements IntoResponse.
    // It will be serialized to the right response event automatically by the runtime
    let resp = Response::builder()
        .status(200)
        .header("content-type", "application/json")
        .body(json!(parsed).to_string().into())
        .map_err(Box::new)?;
    Ok(resp)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_max_level(tracing::Level::INFO)
        // disable printing the name of the module in every log line.
        .with_target(false)
        // disabling time is handy because CloudWatch will add the ingestion time.
        .without_time()
        .init();

    run(service_fn(function_handler)).await
}
```

The idea here is that I want to return the response from the binary in JSON format.

I'm compiling the function with **cargo lambda** which is producing **bootstrap** file, then I'm zipping it manually by including the **bootstrap** binary and the **myProgram** binary.

When I test my function in the lambda panel by sending event to it I get the response with the right headers etc. but the response body is empty.
I'm deploying my function thru the aws panel, on **Custom runtime on Amazon Linux 2** by uploading the zip file.

When I test locally with **cargo lambda watch** and **cargo lambda invoke** the response body is filled with the **myProgram** stdout parsed to json.

Any ideas or thoughts on what goes wrong in the actual cloud are much appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to execute a command in aws lambda from a Rust runtime? Are you sure that this is actually working? I mean the response is empty maybe because there is no output??

Comment: yup, as I've described, on local when I invoke the function with cargo lambda invoke I'm receiving the output from the myProgram formated as json

Comment: I'm not saying on your local, but in AWS lambda, are you sure the ./myProgram runs? I mean can you print the content of `program` somehow? Maybe the `output` is empty because ./myProggram didn't run

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Not sure why I didn't think of checking STDERR in the beginning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem was with the dynamically linked libraries in the binary. It is actually python binary and it was missing specific version of GLIBC.
The easiest solution in my case was to compile **myProgram** on Amazon Linux 2